# Rear wheel thru axle with no lever

Tags: repair, rear-wheel, through-axle

I have a Cube Attain Road, but the rear thru axle puzzles me! I want to remove the rear wheel in order to attach the bike to a Wahoo Kickr 5. How do I get the axle out? When I unscrew the bolt I cannot pull in anything! I do not know which model it is. Attached images from left and right side and bolt out:

[image][image][image]

Comment: I suspect the unscrewed bolt is not supposed to unscrew.  What happens if you undo that screw on the drive side?  Can you then pull the axle out drive side?

Comment: Starting to think the 9mm QR got it right. Why does the world need so many variations of fastening a though axle?   What was wrong with the QR 'Flip lever, done' on 99.9% of bikes (DT Swiss has an 'improvement' that confused me for a minute or two when I first saw it) .

Comment: @mattnz Each method has their own pros and cons. The "flip cam lever" type is more convenient but doesn't clamp as hard as the now-popular tooled, hex bolt style. DT and others with their "turn screw handle" is a little better, but not much. Then Cervelo has their fancy RAT system for fast access, SR Suntour has something similar..... oh my.

Comment: 'female axles' are a thing, this could be one, in which case you are supposed to unscrew at both sides, then perhaps slightly open the chainstays to get the wheel out. Or perhaps in this case also unscrew that PH (PZ?) screw of what supposedly is the derailler hanger. Clearer picture of drive side would help; is it the same as the non-drive side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping me out. I finally figured out that the thru axle is a Syntace X12 - that was difficult for me to confirm. I took the bike to my local repair shop and they were able to locate the problem. It seems that the axle was not installed correctly when the bike was assembled initially. The axle was skewed and had over time locked itself into place. I am not sure how they will remove it, but I hope they will be able to fix it without damaging the carbon frame. Thank you everyone for your efforts!

Comment: Ah, so my suspicion was correct. The designers meant well, but the execution was poor in my opinion. Generally, if something is held together only by threadlocker, it’s not the optimal design.

Comment: There should have been some kind of pin, key or other retaining element, poor engineering.

Comment: Be wary of that Syntace X12 I know they don’t fit my Cube Attain GTC race 2020. If it fits all and well good, if it doesn’t let the shop install it, that way if they bugger up the threads in the carbon frame they’re liable

Answer (score 4):

The 2020/21 models uses an X-12 thru axle. The Cube manual indicates the axle is threaded from the non-drive-side. In that configuration, the thru axle threads into an end cap on the drive-side.
If the bike model is prior to 2020, perhaps the thru axle is inserted from the drive-side.
https://www.cube.eu/en/service/manuals/

Comment: Good observation, but unfortunately the OP does seem to be unthreading their thru-axle from the non-drive side (lower photo). And somehow they only got some sort of end cap out of there, which shouldn't be the case, so the mystery continues.

Comment: They might have changed the design slightly, on my cube it’s one axle that threads on the frame, a normal X12 won’t fit mine as the threads are different. It’s almost identical to the Syntace X12 with a tapered thread.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R7RnP_1Si5ZFVYBptFqIgxS63zmXQej1/view?usp=drivesdk my one for reference, the other end is just a standard one piece hollow for the hex

Answer (score 1):

Could you take a video of what happens when you unscrew the axle? That's how you would undo it. Stick a suitable hex wrench in there and unscrew it like you would with any bolt. Is something broken and the axle isn't coming out?

Comment: I have added the image of bolt unscrewed.

Comment: @nathfn Oh what the. That's beyond my experience then, sorry to disappoint.

Comment: @nathfn that's awfully short for a stormtrooper, er through axle.  The point of a through axle is to go through the wheel securing both sides together.  What's under the black cap on the right hand side, if you remove the phiips screw ?   I've searched and can't find a manual for this bike.  Also confirm the rear wheel is stock.   Try sticking a couple of hex tools down where the bolt came out - might be a hidden socket in the dark.

Comment: @Criggie The Phillips screw is going to be holding in the threaded insert (that teardrop shaped thing). My suspicion is that the steel bolt pictured is intended to make the tool fitting more durable (instead of having an aluminum hex), but the design I’m not so sure of. Surely it’s not just held in with red threadlocker or something??? Defer to more experience.

Comment: This is a great question - I have no idea how it is built, but I want to stick a camera down the hole and see what's there.  There has to be something more, like the rest of the axle.  And if its two disconnected parts, then its not really a through axle.  Perhaps the pictured stub-bolt threads into the head of a second bolt ?

Comment: @Criggie: my humble guess is that something has come apart that should have stayed together because there is thread-locker missing on the short stepped bolt.

Comment: Cube have there own thru axle, it just undoes from the non drive side, be careful not to cross thread anything, on the carbon frames they’re not standard thread. I have the GTC race, I suspect there the same.